# Is it possible to make an application that never has any hard page faults or has them all upon starting the application?

Tags: language-agnostic

Is it possible to make an application that never has any hard page faults or has them all upon starting the application?

Comment: yes, if it locks all its pages in RAM and doesn't mmap any files.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is can happen very easily.

In fact, most simple processes when run back to back on most systems with a page cache will have zero hard faults, since everything (code and data0 is in the disk cache.

Here's a simple example on my system:

```
$ perf stat -e faults,major-faults,minor-faults true

 Performance counter stats for 'true':

                42      faults                                                      
                 0      major-faults                                                
                42      minor-faults                                                

       0.000569273 seconds time elapsed
```

There were a total of 42 faults but all of them soft/minor.